# Selecting a picker value fastly when it has more values in iOS

Tags: ios, performance, picker

I am using [ActionSheetStringPicker](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)  to show list and slect any one from that list..

```
  ActionStringDoneBlock done = ^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {

   };

ActionStringCancelBlock cancel = ^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {

    NSLog(@"Block salutation Picker Canceled");

};

[ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select App" rows:arrApplist  initialSelection:SelectedAppIndex doneBlock:done cancelBlock:cancel origin:btnrest];
```

Here my arrApplist has thousands of values, Now If i want to select the last one i was supposed to scroll to the last the end form first(which takes more time even i know what i want to select).. So I want to provide two more options to select the required one easily..

1.Want to provide search bar

2.Selcting a value with alphabetIndex(which is some thing like [this](http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2749/4231826145_01089881ce.jpg)).

Please guide me how to achieve above behaviours...

Thank you..

Comment: Instead of picker, use tableview with search bar and alphabet index also.  Tableview will solve scrolling longer list of values

Comment: Yeah That might be the easy way, I want to provide done and cancel buttons. Better If I create own design instead of actionstringPikcer